# How to publish article from tinymce into specific aspx file/page

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, tinymce

I have a 'static' page with an article on my webportal, in asp.net.

I need to modify and store data from this page in a db, already made tables, connectionstrings, etc.

My problem is, that i use `tinymce` to edit articles. And i don't know how to have just one page loaded on it, instead of creating a new one everytime.

For example, in articles case, they are a 'dynamic' entity on the webportal, they are stored on db table, and then showed by `ID`. In this case i just need to edit and insert changes of a single page.

Let's say i have `www.mydomain.com/page.aspx` i need to load that `page.aspx` into the editor, from the webadmin interface, modify it, and then save changes, all this stored into a row in my db, already have all the definitions and tables for that.

I just need to know how to load that specific page into `tinymce` modify it, and then store it into my db.

Can anyone point me into the right direction here?

I hope i've explained myself.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am having trouble understanding what you are trying to accomplish. I use tinymce to update pages on my website in real time, through an admin page. Here is the gutted code that is essential to using tinymce:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <div style="width: 1024px; margin: 0px auto; background: #ededed;">
            <div style="width: 980px; margin: 0px auto;">
                <textarea id="TinyMCE" runat="server"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Codebehind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (rdr.Read())
    {
        TinyMCE.InnerText = (string)rdr["HTML"];
    }
}

protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string RenderedHTML = TinyMCE.InnerText;
    string query = "UPDATE cms.Main SET HTML = @Text WHERE ID = @ID";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Text", SqlDbType.Text).Value = RenderedHTML;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TargetPage;
}
```

As you can see, tinymce operates in a textarea. Getting and setting this textarea sets and retrieves the raw html. Tinymce only formats it for visual editing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention, nevermind, i'm going to open a new, more specific question, thank you anyways.